# Return dictionary value as tuple or list from a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a long string which I'm reading from a file line by line.I'm trying to convert the lines to dictionary and trying to check if the given is present in the dictionary key values it has to return true.

**Example:**

```
>>> data
'Xyz         pqrs,uvw'
>>> dict(line.split(',') for line in data.strip().splitlines())
{'Xyz         pqrs': 'uvw'}
```

This is the output I got

**Expected Result:**

in tuples

```
 {'Xyz' : ('pqrs','uvw')}
```

or list

```
{'Xyz' : ['pqrs','uvw']}
```

And if the 'pqrs' is present in data.values() it has to print "Yes"

```
  >>> data2
    {'Xyz': ['pqrs', 'uvw']}
  >>>


  >>> if 'pqrs' in (d for d in data2.values()):
  ...  print "yes"
  ...

  >>> if 'pqrs' in data2.values():
  ...     print "yes"
  ...
```

I tried both the ways but didn't got anything from the output.

Any hint would be helpfull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the dictionary with a nested dictionary-comprehension:

```
>>> data = """Xyz         pqrs,uvw
... Abc             foo,bar,blub"""
>>> d = {key: values.split(",") for key, values in 
            (line.split() for line in data.splitlines())}
>>> d
{'Xyz': ['pqrs', 'uvw'], 'Abc': ['foo', 'bar', 'blub']}
```

Then check containment with `any`:

```
>>> any("pqrs" in v for v in d.values())
True
```

---

Update: Since you seem to be using Python 2.6, before the existence of [dict-comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/), you'll have to use this equivalent form:

```
>>> d = dict((key, values.split(",")) for key, values in 
             (line.split() for line in data.splitlines()))
```

Comment: I'm getting invalid syntax ? >>> d = {key : values.split(",") for key,values in (line.split() for line in data.splitlines()) }
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    d = {key : values.split(",") for key,values in (line.split() for line in data.splitlines()) }
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Dict-Comprehensions are new in Python 2.7 or so (i.e., not what new). Alternatively, try `dict((key, values.split(",")) for ... )`

Comment: I'm using python 2.6. Thanks I got it

Answer (score 0):

You have to clarify your rules. But from what you've shown us this regular expression should do the job

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'[\s,]*')
result = {}
for line in data.strip().splitlines():
    parts = pattern.split(line)
    key = parts[0]
    values = parts[1:]
    if 'pqrs' in values:
        print 'yes'
    result[key] = values
```